# Who are you ordering to when you use rituals to trigger your powers?

Tags: creature-design, super-powers, trans-humanism

Sorry for the look of my question, i'm using a phone, english is not my primary language, and this is my first post in StackExchange. Editing might be useful afterwards.

**Context**

You probably know that a lot of pop culture characters, especially manga characters, are used to tell the name of an attack before actually doing it (or make body pauses, or eat a special food, or wear a special clothe). In fact, those *rituals* are meant for another entity which is the real vessel of the ability triggered by the *ritual*.

**The reason of my question**

It looks like you use a *ritual* or *treat* to make your dog/horse/dragon do a barrel roll/ stand on only 2 feet / breath fire. Except that you seem to have the dog in your own self.

**Who are those entities that gives powers to humans?**

The answer must include at least the human doing the *ritual* and an entity, real holder of the ability

Good answers includes consideration of :

The ability is triggered only by a particular ritual

Some people can use those abilities but most others don't

Multiple people can use the same ability (like most sayans who can become **super** sayans)

People obtain abilities sometime through training, sometime through emotional situations and sometime only by waiting

**Own unsatisfactory answers**

Demons, angels or creature from another realm seems to be a good proposition, but why does they respond to particular rituals and people only?

Humans with powers are in fact androids with nanobots voice activated able to trigger special abilities. This proposition constrain the world to be highly advanced, and no regular humans seems able to obtain abilities via life-changing experience which would be better

Comment: It seems like you're looking for a justification for the trope 'Calling Your Attacks', and there are a lot of good explanations. Sure, one of them is that the worse itself has power (Harry Potter, for instance) but there's also schools of thought that just use the word as a mental focus - kind of like a shortcut (Harry Dresden). That aside, this is a very vague questions with a lot of potential answers, so it might get closed unless you can be more specific about just what you want.

Comment: This asks several questions in one and probably would benefit from being broken down.

Comment: Whomever is answering is whomever the author wants to be the answerer. I think this would be either story or opinion based.

Comment: This is too broad and subjective. Anyway, my two cents: take a look at Kendo. The rules impose that duel participants shout before attacking, and then shout the body part they're aiming at while striking. It's mostly form and focus.

Answer (score 1):

"Own unsatisfactory answers

Demons, angels or creature from another realm seems to be a good proposition, but why does they respond to particular rituals and people only?"

I will build on this as it's something I can work with. The rest needs to be better explained.

Why would and angel or demon or creature do so?

Many reasons.

1-Because those words have a correspondence in the magical world that is much like science in ours.
We know in our world that if you construct a gun properly and pull the trigger and it does not jam then a bullet will come through the barrel and keep going until it loses all power, not sure of the technical name, or hits something.

Well. In the magical world those words of power hold binding power over these creatures. It's like how flammable materials work. Throw a lit match at that open container of a highly flammable material and the material will catch fire **100%**
of the time.

2-They entice mortals with power to gain something in return.
This could be anything from full on possession and controlling their body or, I actually have this in a world of mine, small "gifts" that they feed on, like blood.
So it's a mutually beneficial relationship between the two sides.

3-Angels are fighting demons, demons are fighting angels. Earth, or your realm, is the battlefield and humans are the proxy soldiers.
If you imagine this as the traditional good vs evil fight with conforming or controlling the humans, or whatever is going on in the setting, is an essential goal of those creatures

Let me explain. Say entity A creates 2 opposing sides and decides that the battle for human salvation/destruction is their ultimate goal.
Then demons try to draw in mortals with packs that grants great power but forfeits the soul while angels do something similar.
This could even be reflected in the type of power. Destruction is demonic while restoration is angelic.
Fun times when a soldier with super restoration has to suffer pain as he fights through demonic fireballs. You know, interesting side effects.

4-Point 3 however here it is not a fight for good or bad. Merely the side with the most followers gains power in the halls of the heaven, or whatever other dimension you have, so it is a matter of practical considerations.
Like how a sports club wants more fans to sell more tickets and merchandise

5-We don't know. Think the old ones of Lovecraft. We simply can't comprehend why do these things play along.

6-We don't know anything about that. Think of it as speculative science and proposed untested theories. Or heck. Even actual science. Like hey lets assume that gravity is a warp in space time, why is it that?
OK. Why do protons do their own thing that way?
Why do fire burn?
I suppose this could either be: we can't explain things to infinity.
Or: things have a nature; it is just so
Or: Maybe we will figure it out one day.
All we know is that when we say kblaaam stuff go boom. So far so good.

7-Chained titans of old.
Another idea that just came to me.
Imagine this original powerful race of things that held great power and can do a lot of wacky stuff. I mean powerful magic.
So at a Zeus stand in, or even him, decided to chain them and force them to do whatever the humans order granted it is following the established lore of the world. Like no bringing back the dead for example.
Then maybe Zeus got bored or he is chasing tail in another galaxy or whatever.
They are forced to do as we say.
Heck. You can have them lose their own minds and even decay to the point where they are but a skeleton of their former selves, forever lost to the world of thinking and feeling and free will. Their bones melted with the chains, their minds dissolved by the currents of time. They are mere shadows of the mighty gods they were. And forever they are bound to be our slaves.

Answer (score 0):

***To thine own subconscious be true:***

All this ritual is the equivalent of a placebo. Placebos REALLY affect your health, by making your mind do something it logically shouldn't. Like screen out pain. People can even benefit from placebos when they know it's a placebo, because a doctor tells them the placebo works to affect their subconscious. This is you, telling your subconscious what to do. Magic defies logic and common sense, and only the instinctual parts of the mind can control it. In the same way that gurus can control their bodies and autonomic functions by disciplines and practice, the mage controls the uncontrollable by ritualizing the process.

A monk can spend years learning to control his breathing, and a wizard can follow the same route for magic. But in the same way a desperate mother can lift a car off their child (this is a real phenomenon called hysterical strength), extreme situations can cause your wizard to gain abilities. (many martial arts moves are understood to involve this same hysterical strength release, but moved to conscious control).

The magical ability is magi-physics, so anyone's subconscious can DO it, but only a trained (or rarely, self-triggered) mind actually does. In the same way a placebo tricks your body into doing something it should know to do anyway, your mind may need convincing that an angel, devil, god, spirit, or saint is involved. Once that is the path you use, it's really hard to accept another. Since the magic isn't following conventional logic, the brain creates a logic to explain it.